# How to make text input with floated-right button

Tags: html, css

I want to make an input text-field where I want a text-field in left and button in right front of input and attached with input text-field. Consider the HTML snippet below...

```html
<div class="textbox-feild">
   <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
</div>
 <div class="button-field">
   <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:flex` to `warp` div:

```css
    .warp{
    display:flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="warp">
    <div class="textbox-feild">
       <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
    </div>
     <div class="button-field">
       <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
    </div>
 </div>
```

You can do it with `display: inline-block;`

```css
    .textbox-feild,.button-field{
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="textbox-feild">
       <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
    </div>
     <div class="button-field">
       <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
    </div>
```

Comment: @lonely tell me for more help

Answer (score 1):

Make divs `inline-block;`

```
.textbox-feild, .button-field {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<style>
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
.textbox-feild, .button-field {
    display: inline-block;
    
}
input {
   font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
<div class="textbox-feild">
   <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
</div>
 <div class="button-field">
   <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Use these style if you want no space between the input and button

```
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
.textbox-feild, .button-field {
    display: inline-block;

}
input {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to both the div

```css
.textbox-feild,
.button-field {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox-feild">
  <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
</div>
<div class="button-field">
  <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
.contain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="textbox-feild">
    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
  </div>
  <div class="button-field">
    <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Or**:

Apply the same class to the both and style it with `inline-block` like so:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different methods.

Just check the fiddles:

`display: inline-block';` :-  https://jsfiddle.net/vhxoqk8p/

`float: left;` :- https://jsfiddle.net/eg30js52/

`display: inline-flex;` :- https://jsfiddle.net/rpcesufb/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'll do it easily, using only `float: left;`:
(I also corrected typo issues like `feild`)

```css
.textbox-field,
.button-field {
  float: left;           /* All-in-one: display inline and avoid the gap between them */
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox-field">
  <input type="text" class="textfield" name="Email" placeholder="Email *" title="Email * is mandatory and it should be a valid email address">
</div>
<div class="button-field">
  <input type="button" class="buttonfield" value="Sign up now">
</div>
```

Hope it helps.